# Ошибка 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу телеграмм бота и у меня не работает функция перевода текста, а именно строка

```
translation = translator.translate(text, dest='ru')
```

для примера пытался ввести слово "dog" и выводит ошибку 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' помимо этого функция detect определяет язык слова не правильно

```
import telebot
from googletrans import Translator
from langdetect import detect 

def translate(message):
    translator = Translator(service_urls=['translate.google.com'])
    text = message.text
    try:
        detected_lang = detect(text)
        if detected_lang == 'ru' or detected_lang == 'rus':
            translation = translator.translate(text, dest='en')
        else:
            translation = translator.translate(text, dest='ru')
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, translation.text)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Произошла ошибка: {str(e)}')
```

Пытался сделать через библиотеку langid метод classify, проблему языка это решило, но ошибка та же, читал, что может влиять версия библиотеки googletrans, но какую не ставил, та же проблема (к слову мой знакомый запускал код у себя и у него все работало, но вот у меня почему то нет)

Извините, не знаю, какая именно часть ошибки пригодится, поэтому вот весь вывод консоли

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\МП\PycharmProjects\telega\main.py", line 103, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1043, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1118, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 147, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 90, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\МП\PycharmProjects\telega\main.py", line 55, in translate
    translation = translator.translate(text, dest='ru')
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 182, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in do
    self._update()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
    code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: добавьте к вопросу ошибку полностью, пожалуйста

Comment: @zrx я добавил вывод ошибки

Comment: попробуйте обновить библиотеку через команду `pip install --upgrade googletrans`, возможно поможет

Comment: также попробуйте другой метод получения токена - `translator = Translator(service_urls=['translate.google.com'], client=True)`

если эти варианты не помогут, можете использовать другой модуль для перевода - deepl (как вариант)

Comment: @zrx Проблема решилась, решил полностью удалить py charm и python и заново установить и все работает, прошу прощения, мой вопрос оказался глупым, спасибо за помощь